# "d = ut + 1/2 at^2"? How to solve this in java?

Tags: java

```
public class DistanceTravelled {

    static double testcase11 = 12.5;

    static double testcase12 = 4.4;

    static double testcase13 = 10;

    public static void main(String args[]){
        DistanceTravelled testInstance= new DistanceTravelled();
        double result = testInstance.distance(testcase11,testcase12,testcase13);
        System.out.println(result);
    }

    //write your code here
    public double distance(double u, double a, double t){
        double d = d = u*t + 1/2*a*t^2 ;
        return d;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

The `^` is not the exponentiation operator in Java, so `t^2` won't yield what you need.  `^` is [the bitwise-exclusive-or operator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html) in Java.

The simplest solution is to multiply `t` by itself.  Be careful also not to perform integer division with `1/2`.

```
double d = u*t + 0.5*a*t*t ;
```

Comment: thku..........so much.............bt i still didnt get the reason of using t*t intstead of ^.

Comment: The `^` does NOT exponentiate in Java.  It does bitwise-exclusive-or, a different operation.  See [Bitwise operation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation) for an explanation of that operation.